# A certainly erroneous proof for $a \sin(x)+ b \cos(x) = c \cdot \cos(x- \alpha)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, solution-verification

I'd be grateful if someone could look over the proof for the following: Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ Show that there exist $c \ge0$ and $0 \le \alpha \le 2 \pi$ such that

$a \sin(x)+ b \cos(x) = c \cdot \cos(x- \alpha)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

$a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)) \implies c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \land \cos(\alpha)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \sin(\alpha)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Factoring out yields: $a \sin(x)+b \cos(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\sin(x)\cos(\alpha)-\cos(x)\sin(\alpha))$

$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x - \alpha) \implies$ since $\sin(x- \alpha) =\cos(\alpha - x):a \sin(x)+ b \cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cdot \cos(x- \alpha)$ which is to say $c \cdot \cos(x- \alpha)$

I'm sure there are some errors in there, so I appreciate the help and the time one spends on helping me here.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think $\sin(x-\alpha) = \cos(\alpha-x)$? It is wrong.

Comment: $\cos (x)$ is next to $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and you picked $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. Then why, in the next line, $\cos(x)$ is multiplied by $\sin(\alpha)$?